# Directory (Folder) WITHOUT any name

Tags: windows

How can be there any directory without any name? And if it's possible, what does it signify.

I had some data on my pendrive which, after inserting into somebody else's system, didn't show any content. I got the solution from a link (using attrib -s -h command).

After that, I could see the data but I observed a folder without any name. I could see the data located in that 'unnamed folder' without any issue. Even cmd doesn't show any name for it; nor does the address bar.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's actually blank and not a "space" (ASCII 32) or "null" character (ASCII 255)?

Comment: No! I am not. But I didn't know how to check it. Te best I could come up with, was check using cmd.Please let me know how I can check whether the name is a NULL or a SPACE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether the name is actually one or more space characters.

Comment: How can I check that? I thought of doing the same by created a new folder and tried to name it space (hit the space key) but it didn't.

Comment: A simple way would be to do a directory listing of the parent directory and highlight and copy the area that contains the directory name (your file manager may even allow you to select and copy the directory name as a right click option).  Another source would be to right-click on the directory and look at Properties.  The name area would be a place to highlight and copy it.  Paste it into an Excel cell between two "marker characters" and use string functions to identify what's there.

Comment: The question and answers/comments all address a scientific curiosity about the directory.  If your actual goal is just to use the directory, right-click on it in your file manager and rename it (you wouldn't even need to know what the existing name actually is).  Of course once you do that, you will never know what it was.

Comment: My goal was to know what was happening since i was unaware of this trick/way to name a directory. Got it! It was non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

By using Alt+255 to insert a non-break space in the filename

[creata a folder without name in win7](http://windows.mercenie.com/windows-classic/file-folder-without-name/)